# R: splitting string that has format like this "xxx; yyy; zzz;"

Tags: r, split

The raw data I got is like this and they are all in one column

```
John;Peter;Eric;
Susan;Mary;Kate;
```

But I want to split them to three separate columns

```
John  Peter  Eric
Susan Mary   Kate
```

Can anyone show me how to do it in R? Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, the format of raw data is data.frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'col1', ';')
#    col1_1 col1_2 col1_3
#1:   John  Peter   Eric
#2:  Susan   Mary   Kate
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, col1, into=paste0('col', 1:4), ';')[-4]
#    col1  col2 col3
#1  John Peter Eric
#2 Susan  Mary Kate
```

Or

```
 extract(df1, col1, into=paste0('col', 1:3), '([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+)')
 #   col1  col2 col3
 #1  John Peter Eric
 #2 Susan  Mary Kate
```

Or using `base R`

```
 as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(df1$col1, ';')))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("John;Peter;Eric;", "Susan;Mary;Kate;"
 )), .Names = "col1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `fread()` to the lot

```
x <- "John;Peter;Eric;
Susan;Mary;Kate;"

data.table::fread(x, header = FALSE, drop = 4)
#       V1    V2   V3
# 1:  John Peter Eric
# 2: Susan  Mary Kate
```

And for directly returning a data frame,

```
data.table::fread(x, header = FALSE, drop = 4, data.table = FALSE)
#      V1    V2   V3
# 1  John Peter Eric
# 2 Susan  Mary Kate
```

And for a fast matrix that you can convert to data frame,

```
library(stringi)
stri_split_fixed(stri_split_lines1(x), ";", omit = TRUE, simplify = TRUE)
#      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]  
# [1,] "John"  "Peter" "Eric"
# [2,] "Susan" "Mary"  "Kate"
```

Comment: Is there a way using fread() without creating a vector x? since the actual data set I am dealing with is quite large (instead of just a 3 by 2 data frame). Thanks!

Comment: @kelvinfrog - Yes, of course you can just read it from the file.  Just substitute the file name for `x`

Answer (score 1):

```
base R: 

  matrix(regmatches(x,gregexpr("([aA-zZ]+)",x,perl=TRUE))[[1]],ncol=3,byrow=T)
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]  
[1,] "John"  "Peter" "Eric"
[2,] "Susan" "Mary"  "Kate"
```